# konva.js behavior when the mouse button is pressed

Tags: onmousedown, konvajs

I ask if konva.js may behave like other graphics libraries as Raphael.js or Paper.js when the mouse is pressed and then leaves the canvas or browser window, this video illustrates the difference in behavior by default.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeBNJiN_Vdo

Is there a trick to konva.js work the same way?

(google translator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed in develop version.
You can get the last build here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/konvajs/konva/master/konva.js